# Matrix representation of $R^0\rightarrow R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Consider the zero linear map, $R^0(=0)\rightarrow R^m$. Then is a matrix representation of this map a $m\times0$ matrix? Does there exist a matrix representation of this map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any linear map between finite rank free modules has a matrix representation. In this case, as you say correctly, the matrix is just $()$, the empty matrix, because the empty set is a basis of $R^0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!